# Error in startup script: child process exited abnormally

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

am working on my first tcl/tk project but whenever i run the script, it shows me this error

```
Error in startup script: child process exited abnormally
while executing
"exec which [string tolower $css]"
(procedure "::Ui::scriptSettings" line 16)
invoked from within
"::Ui::scriptSettings $::Ui::scriptSettings"
(procedure "::Ui::Ui" line 15)
invoked from within
"::Ui::Ui"
(file "./init.tcl" line 266)
```

and it is always on this line

```
$installationPath insert 0 [exec which [string tolower $css]]
```

$css is a path that exist on /usr/bin folder

This is the procedure the error is triggered

```
foreach css $::Ui::CSS {
    set cssScriptLabel [labelframe $settingsCssFrame.cssLabel$i -text $css]
    set optionalArgument [label $cssScriptLabel.optArg$i -text "Optional Arguments"]
    set optArgEntry [entry $cssScriptLabel.optArgEntry$i]

    set outFileLabel [label $cssScriptLabel.outFile$i -text "OutFile/OutDir"]
    set outFileEntry [entry $cssScriptLabel.outFileEntry$i]
    set installationPathLabel [label $cssScriptLabel.installLabel$i -text "Intallation Path"]
    set installationPath [entry $cssScriptLabel.installPath$i]
    $installationPath delete 0 end
    $installationPath insert 0 [exec which [string tolower $css]]
    grid $cssScriptLabel -pady 5 -columnspan 1
    grid $optionalArgument $optArgEntry -sticky news
    grid $outFileLabel $outFileEntry -sticky news
    grid $installationPathLabel $installationPath
    incr i;
}
```

what i want to do is to replace the text in the entry box with the path name of $css

Comment: And what does `which <css>` show when you type it in manually at the shell prompt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like the `which` call is failing to find the program. When it fails to find it, it exits with a non-zero exit code, and Tcl interprets that (correctly!) as a problem, and raises an error. You can handle those errors with `catch` or `try`.

```
try {
    $installationPath insert 0 [exec which [string tolower $css]]
} trap CHILDSTATUS {} {
    # No such program; recover here...
}
```

With `catch` instead (which catches *all* errors, including things like syntax blunders and so on):

```
if {[catch {
    $installationPath insert 0 [exec which [string tolower $css]]
}]} {
    # No such program; recover here...
}
```